# zookeeper watcher: NodeChildrenChangedEvent only fired if parent node update

Tags: apache-zookeeper

The Zookeeper Watcher is capturing child node adds and deletes, but ONLY does so if I change the value of the parent node.

For example for parent1, Watcher Events of type nodeChildrenChanged are only fired if I update the value of parent1 first, which triggers a NodeDataChanged Watcher Event.

Anyone else seeing this?

--John

Answer (score 2):

Ah, figured it out. Needed to invoke zk.exists(path, watcher) to initialize for data events and zk.getChildren(path, watcher) to initialize for child events.